# Regex finding file names

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with the REGEX to match

```
../_assets/applications/cleaning/*logo.png
```

"*" being the file name which can also follow an underscore or dash so

```
../_assets/applications/cleaning/main_logo.png
```

OR

```
../_assets/applications/cleaning/main-logo.png
```

this is as far as I got

```
\assets\/applications\/cleaning\/
```

Comment: I am basically using it to replace /cleaning/XXXX.png to /logos/XXX.png

Comment: No, sorry, I have some files which are not logos that are in the cleaning folder, so I need to change the path of only logos to the logo folder

Comment: That didn't work for me but thanks

Comment: What was the problem with @chris85's regex? Looks okay to me.

Comment: Ah, that has worked, I think I must have copied it incorrectly - thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've moved that to answer.

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk in a regex is a quantifier allowing zero or more of the previous character/group. So you first expression would allow zero or more forward slashes. You can use a `.` with a `*` to allow for zero or more of any character (excluding new line). So something like:

```
\/cleaning\/(.+?logo\.png)$
```

should find all the images you want, then:

```
/logos/$1
```

should replace them as you wanted.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dmAjjv/1/